# Pass data to Broadcast receiver on Boot, android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

Thanks in advance for the help.

I have a SharedPreference object that is created by an activity in my app.  On device boot up, how might I be able to get the values I have stored in this SharedPreference object?  This is what I have thus far (which isn't running on boot up either for some reason / the only reason I want to start the activity here is to make sure my DeviceBootReceiver code is working correctly / the activity works correctly as I have independently started it).  Notice that I have changed class names for privacy reasons

xml

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="20"
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:name="app"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="app"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <activity
        android:name="activity"
        android:label="activity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

broadcast code

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, activity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the the `sharedPreference` as you would in your Activity, but now with `context`

e.g.

```
context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

or

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

depending on how it was called in your Activity.

**Edit:**
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>` should be same level as `<application>` not inside `<application>`

Comment: How do I know that context will be an instance of the right activity?  Also, the code that I have is not running on boot either.

Comment: you do not need context to be the same activity. Using any context within the application gives you access to the same **Share** Preferences

Comment: okay cool beans.  Why might not my activity be starting on boot?

Comment: I don't understand this question

Comment: So the broadcast receiver that I have created is supposed to run when I boot the android device, ie if I install my app and turn off the phone, when I turn the phone back on, the onReceive in DeviceBootReceiver should be called.  To make sure this is happening correctly, I am trying to start the activity called "activity".  However, the UI for this method does not appear on boot.  If I manually start the activity though, it works okay.  This indicates that I have problem either in my manifest or DeviceBootReceiver class (ie onReceive not being called on boot).

Comment: **Activity** contains  UI, and **Broadcast Receiver** is just a background job, waiting to be called, it contains no UI, they are independent of each other. An example of common **Broadcast Receier** would be an alarm receiver, which is being called on a specific time, then you may send a notification.

Comment: Yes, BroadcastReceiver is an alarm receiver.  When a device boots, it should send a message to DeviceBootReceiver and start the activity I have specified.  If it starts, the activity UI should appear.  Otherwise, DeviceBootReceiver's on onReceive method was not called.  Which is what my problem is, onReceive is either not being called or I am not starting my activity correctly.  This means that I have a problem either in my manifest or in DeviceBootReceiver.

Comment: Your questions on top is totally not related to this.... Anyway I have updated my answer, try changing your receiver like this to start your activity...

Comment: can you explain what "packageName" is?  Also this isn't similar to any of the techniques I've seen others explain to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: The xml code was the issue.  Thank you.  The edit you made regarding the BroadcastReceiver is not needed.  It runs using my original code (which is similar to how most people seem to accomplish what I want).  In the future please don't be condescending when helping others.  If everyone wrote perfect code StackOverflow would not be needed.

Comment: I am sorry if you think so. However I had answered 2 questions in 1, Shared Preferences and debug for start activity failure. Please put it into separate questions next time, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask